# How can I Restrict Users on OTT Platform (Like 3 Stream/Account) [Device Limitation]

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I'm working on a OTT Platform For API using Django Rest Framework & for Website React & for App React Native.

I'm trying to add Device limitation on account like 3 user can watch at a same time per account. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is two options for that 1. Websocket and another one is firebase.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a model `Device` linked to your User in which you will save the different devices a user is using. And then you'll add a clean method to prevent from creating more than three devices.

Comment: No, If one user stop the player, then another user should watch...

Comment: You said in your question it was per account, why would another user could watch when the first user stops the player ? I didn't understand it was linked between users